# Ubuntu 18.04 - Install packaged roundcube with nginx instead of apache2

Tags: nginx, apt, roundcube, ubuntu-18.04

under Ubuntu 18.04, I'd like to install the provided packaged version of RoundCube using nginx instead of apache2; nginx is already installed and running with php7.2-fpm so I don't need another webserver.

From packages.ubuntu.com I've seen that RoundCube can be installed with apache2 OR lighttp OR php-fpm but every time I rise the:

```
apt --no-install-recommends install roundcube roundcube-plugins php-net-sieve
```

apt still try to install apache2.

Any clue is strongly appreciated to solve this issue.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. But I figured it out. If you look at the package details [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/roundcube-core) you can see that it's *requiring* `libapache2-mod-php` or `php`. For whatever reason, `php7.2-fpm` does not satisfy the `php` package requirement. Just **`apt install roundcube php`** and you should get a much smaller list of packages it wants to install, and apache will be absent.